# sympyで式をプラスとマイナスで分解する方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: python, sympy

1+2*x-3*cos(x)
1番目 1
2番目 +2*x
3番目 -3*cos(x)
標準関数を見つける事ができませんでした。
正規表現の方法になりますか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

SymPyが項の順番を正規化(?)してしまうので、目的にあうかわかりませんが、こんな感じでいかがでしょうか。

```
from sympy import cos
from sympy.abc import x, y

y = 1 + 2 * x - 3 * cos(x)
print(y)
print(y.args)
```

結果

```
2*x - 3*cos(x) + 1
(1, -3*cos(x), 2*x)
```

別解として`y.as_terms()`で項を得ることもできます。